# Take the input from a function and write it on a .txt file, then create a function to close the file

Tags: python, io

1. What is the best way to save user's **input in a .txt file**?

So far, i got to this point, but im stuck when i try to code the **I/O**.

```
# check if the sname that the user has typed is correct and save it to a new .txt file in the same folder as the .py project
sname = 'nicolas'

while True:
    try:
        question = input('Enter your second name:')
        if question == sname:
            print('Ok')
            break
        else:
            if question != sname:
                print("Please, enter your second name correctly...")
    except ValueError:
        print("That wasn't correct, try again...")
```

Comment: If you google how to write a file with Python, you will find thousands of examples.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using `with`

```py
sname = 'nicolas'
question = input('Enter your second name:')
while question.lower() != sname:
    print("Please, enter your second name correctly...")
    question = input('Enter your second name:')
with open("textfile.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(sname)
```